# data dredging and multiple correlation coeficients

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I conducted a study examining variables associated with cardiac disease. I conducted a Pearson correlation analysis examining the correlation between two sets of parameters, I did this for all variable in the study. Of the 10 x-y correlation analyses conducted, 2 were significant at the 0.05 level. Using Prism GraphPad, I was able to set x for example to mean arterial pressure and correlate 9 other variables in one analysis. Of these analyses, 2 were significant at alpha<0.05.

Is this considered a multiple analysis paradigm where alpha should be divided by the number correlation, ie 0.05/10 for significance?
If so, is there a method I should be using to account for multiple analyses?

Comment: Please say more about what you mean by: "I was able to set x for example to mean arterial pressure and correlate 9 other variables in one analysis." Was that some type of multiple regression using all 9 variables together as predictors of mean arterial pressure, or 9 separate correlations of other variables against mean arterial pressure? It would help if you could say more about what you are trying to accomplish with this analysis, as simply looking as correlations is not always the best way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the note. We conducted a study examining blood flow in human conjunctival blood vessels. We measured the velocity of red blood cells and the diameter of the vessel. We also collected data on mean arterial pressure, hematocrit hemoglobin levels, left ventricular  pressure.and  sodium and potassium.  We then performed a post-hoc correlation analysis of all the variables. The only significant findings were the correlation between potassium and vessel diameter and red blood cell flow.  My concern is that we have violated the multiplicity rule in this analysis. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 outcome variables: red-cell velocity and vessel diameter. You have 5 potential predictors: mean arterial pressure, hemoglobin level, left ventricular pressure, serum sodium, and serum potassium. You measured all of these in several instances and examined the 10 correlations of each of the 2 outcome variables against each of the 5 predictors.

For that type of analysis you certainly are running into the [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). If you do 10 independent comparisons when there are no true correlations and accept a p value of 0.05 as the criterion for statistical significance, then you have about a 40% probability of at least 1 false positive finding by chance. So you have to make some adjustment.

The strictest [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn%E2%80%93Bonferroni_correction) with 10 independent comparisons would require a p-value cutoff of (0.05/10) or 0.005 for significance at a false-discovery rate of 0.05. The [Holm method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) still keeps the same protection against making false positives but can be less likely to discard true positives. The correction in the Holm method depends on the particular p values that were found for the individual tests.

You might, however, get more useful results by doing a [multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression). Instead of comparing red-cell velocity against each of the 5 predictors separately, examine how all 5 predictors are related to red-cell velocity when they are *all considered together*. Very often the association of a predictor variable with an outcome variable becomes clearer when other variables are taken into account in this way, enhancing your ability to find true relationships. The significance of one *entire regression model* is examined at the first step rather than 5 separate independent correlations, improving the multiple-comparison problem too.

In your case, I suspect that red-cell velocity and vessel diameter might be inversely related (wider vessels, slower velocity at constant volume flow) so they aren't really independent. That could work in your favor, allowing a *single* [multivariate multiple regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/multivariate-regression-analysis/) model using all your data at once, instead of 2 separate multiple regressions.* At the level of the entire model there is no longer a multiple comparison problem: a single test determines whether the model as a whole is statistically significant. If it is, with all the data taken together you typically have more precise estimates of how each of the predictors is related to the outcome than you would with the separate individual correlations. That improves your power to identify significant associations even if you still need to take multiple comparisons into account for subsequent analysis.

I would recommend getting some local statistical advice on how best to analyze your data and design future experiments. If a study is worth doing at all it is worth doing well, in terms of both the technique and the statistical analysis.

---

*The terminology can be confusing. Multiple regression generally means multiple predictor variables, multivariate regression generally means multiple outcome variables. Not everyone adheres to this convention, however.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful comments. The interesting thing about our findings is that potassium is positively correlated to both diameter and flow. There is good prior evidence that potassium acts as a vasodilator and increases flow in microvessels however this have never been shown in the conjunctival microvascular system. Therefore I suspect the relationships are real.  I will attempt the multiple regression approach. Unfortunately our biostats support team at our institution is booked for several months. I try to conduct as much statistical work myself if possible.